# refresh StatefulShellRoute in flutter

Tags: flutter, router, flutter-go-router, gorouter

here is the scenario, Im using `StatefulShellRoute` to preserve the state of each tab in my app, and when user sign in, or change language of the app, i need to refresh my `StatefulShellRoute` to load new data.

i tried giving a `UniqueKey` to each `StatefulShellBranch` but when i hot reload or use inspector it rebuild the whole application which is bad for performance and development flow.

so is there any clean way to refresh my `StatefulShellRoute` ?